# What is the rxjava version for jdk 17

Tags: rx-java, java-17

We are using rxjava 1.3.8 on java 8. We wish to migrate our code base to java 17. Can we expect that 1.3.8 will continoue working with java 17? If not, what is the recomanded/official version?
Thanks

Comment: see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava.  and "The 2.x version is end-of-life as of **February 28, 2021**", maybe 1.3.8 can/wil run, but I think you need to do some work to use version 3,x

Comment: I'm not aware of any issue running 1.x or 2.x on the latest JDKs. However, support ended for them year(s) ago. Thus if there is a problem, it won't be fixed. I recommend migrating to 3.x which is verified to work even with JDK 20 as of writing this comment.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks. So if I understand you correctly, 1.x is not garenteed to work on jdk 17, but so far, no one complains about it. Right?

Comment: Yes, nobody complained about it and probably nobody really tried it either. May I ask why you did stick to 1.x for so long? Do you have a dependency that is 1.x still?

Comment: So, we are using rxjava 1.x and java 8 for several years now in one of our projecrs. I guess no one upgraded till now since it's just worked fine. But now we must uprade the java to 17 (due to other internal project) and I need to make sure it  won't be messed up due to unsuported dependencies. Specifically rxjava is uses extensivly is our code, so it would save us major migration effort staying with current version.

Comment: @akarnokd Does it make sense?

Comment: I can't think of anything right now that could break just by moving to 17.